# PHP Merging two continous time series data arrays by aligning timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a primary data array that always consists of 600 seconds of data in time ascending order. The data looks like this:

```
[{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:00', 'p_value' => 55 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:01', 'p_value' => 57 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:02', 'p_value' => 51 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:03', 'p_value' => 54 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:04', 'p_value' => 48 }]
```

I have a secondary array which has upto 600 seconds of data. This data is a continuous 'subset' of timestamps of the primary data array, however the starting (and ending) timestamp values can vary:

```
[{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:01', 's_value' => 1221 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:02', 's_value' => 4322 },
{'timestamp' => '2016-10-10T10:00:03', 's_value' => 2414 },]
```

How do I 'align' up the secondary array with the primary via the timestamp, and then add the 's_values' into the primary array, in the most computationally efficient manner?

I've already implemented something very similar using nested foreach loops, however I think this is O(N^2) complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first array is in `$firstArr` and the second array is in `$secondArr` and also assuming that

`$secondArr[count($secondArr)-1]['timestamp] <= $firstArr[count($firstArr)-1]['timestamp'])`

meaning that the second array does not contain a timestamp that may not exist in the first one then the following code does the merge you want in linear time (no O(n^2))

It starts by finding the first timestamp of `$secondArr` inside `$firstArr` and holding its index in a variable. Then it copies the p_values starting from that index.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($firstArr); $i++)
{
    if($firstArr[$i]['timestamp'] == $secondArr[0]['timestamp'])
    {
        $startingIndex = $i;
        break;
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<count($secondArr); $i++)
{
    $firstArr[$startingIndex+$i]['s_value'] = $secondArr[$i]['s_value'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I've implemented it and confirmed it works as intended.